# Update a Cordova/Phonegap (3.2.0) plugin into the project

Tags: android, plugins, cordova

I have self written plugin into `my-plugin/plugin`.

I install it with `cordova plugin add my-plugin/plugin`. Then it appears under `plugins/` and in my Android project.

Now I want to make some changes in this plugin, but I don't know how to deploy these changes into my Android project.

My current workaround is `cordova plugin rm com.my.plugin` and then `cordova plugin add my-plugin/plugin`.

Is there any better way?

```
$ cordova -v
3.2.0-0.2.0
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try just cordova plugin add my-plugin/plugin and skip the remove it seems to do the update even though it reports that its already installed.

Like you all I assumed (or read somewhere, not sure which) that cordova auto updated the plugins when building, I dont think that is the case.

With Phonegap 3.4 there are now hooks which can run based on commands such as before_build, using those you can run a script which updates your plugins each time you run build.

See this blog for more info
http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/

Comment: Simply re-adding them (without removing first) works for me. I can tell because my plugin directory is committed to git, and I see code changes and increased version numbers after running `cordova plugin add` again.

Comment: Re adding the plugin worked for me....
But after running application again it seems like it is running older version.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same question and tried to find any documentation on updating cordova apps but i seems like there is no documentation at all.

So i did it with `rm` and `add` afterwards. 
But i can't believe that there is no better way though :(